# How to get value from Firebase and save in an attribute using java code

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying create a "read" method which will get a value from Firebase (Google server) using android studio (Java) 
I wrote the code below but the problem that the value[0] always returning "" as a value and not the value from the server.
When Im inside the method "onDataChange",the value[0] is equal to the value from the server but outside, its back to the original value.
What is wrong with my code?
please help

```
/**
 * Return value
 *
 * @param parent
 * @param child
 * @param key
 * @return
 */
public static String read(String parent, String child, String key) {
    final String[] value = {""};
    // Get a reference to our posts
    final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference(parent).child(child);

    // Attach a listener to read the data at our posts reference
    ref.child(key).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String str = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            System.out.println(str);
            value[0] = str;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
        }
    });

    return value[0];
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

its an asynchronous method,try something like this

```
    public static String read(String parent, String child, String key) {
    final String[] value = {""};
    // Get a reference to our posts
    final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference(parent).child(child);

    // Attach a listener to read the data at our posts reference
    ref.child(key).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String str = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            System.out.println(str);
            value[0] = str;
            passingValue(value[0]);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
        }
    });

    return value[0];
}

    private void passingValue(String temp){
//do something with your string

}
```

outside the scope of OndataChange,the value won't be retained

Answer (score 1):

This is happening due the asynchronous behaviour of `onDataChange()` method which is called even before  you are getting that data from your database. A quick fix would be to declare and use your array inside `onDataChange()` method like this:

```
ref.child(key).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String[] value = {""}; //declaration of the array
        String str = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
        System.out.println(str);
        value[0] = str;
        passingValue(value[0]);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
    }
});
```

Please see the declaration of the array inside `onDataChange()` method. For a more complex answer, please see my answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847694/how-to-return-datasnapshot-value-as-a-result-of-a-method/47853774), which also contains a reference on how to use that value outside `onDataChange()` method